# Android DefaultHttpClient, HttpPost etc. depricated (SDK 30)

Tags: android, android-studio, http-post

I updated my application but I could not find the new functions we use to upload images.

```
    String photoBase64 = ConvertBitmapToString(selectPhotoBitmap);

    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", "data:image/png;base64," + photoBase64));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", selectPhotoName));

    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(config.FTP + "upload.php");
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                httpclient.execute(httppost);
            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();
```

Deprecateds:

```
NameValuePair in org.apache.http has been deprecated
BasicNameValuePair(String,String) in BasicNameValuePair has been deprecated
DefaultHttpClient() in DefaultHttpClient has been deprecated
HttpPost(String) in HttpPost has been deprecated
UrlEncodedFormEntity in org.apache.http.client.entity has been deprecated
UrlEncodedFormEntity(List<? extends NameValuePair>) in UrlEncodedFormEntity has been deprecated
setEntity(HttpEntity) in HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase has been deprecated
execute(HttpUriRequest) in HttpClient has been deprecated
```

How can I change them with new ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HttpURLConnection https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection or if you want to continue using `httpclient`  add

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy' }
```

in app level gradle

Send the image to server as a file and not base64

```
MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();

         
            builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
//Here image is the absolute path of the file you want to post
            FileBody fbd=new FileBody(new File(image));
            builder.addPart("my_file",fbd);

            for (int index = 0; index < nameValuePairs.size(); index++) {
                builder.addPart(nameValuePairs.get(index).getName(),new StringBody(nameValuePairs.get(index).getValue(),ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN));

            }

           
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);//your url

            HttpEntity entity = builder.build();

            httpPost.setEntity(entity);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            String response = httpEntity.getContent();
```

Comment: I already tried HttpURLConnection but it didnt work.

Comment: Will it be good if you send the image as file and not base64  by using Multipartentitybuilder?

Comment: I have already useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy' } and normally my code is working, I just want to replace them with new ones. Your code has deprecated members.